# HighCharts Stacked Charts xAxis with json not working

Tags: jquery, highcharts

This is the string i am getting from json

```
var str = "6,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28";

 xAxis: {
    categories: []   // want to update this part (HighCharts)
},
```

I am not able to update the xAxis with

```
Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].update({categories:[str]}, true);
```

Please help is there a issue with syntax??

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string into an array of strings, for example:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(str.split(','));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6y1v7f20/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setCategories